# Notification appearance does not work

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications

I have an app in the Play store, the firebase push notification icon looks like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/918D2.png

So I added this in my Manisfest:

```
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/iconfirebase" />

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

This worked when I used my cell phone as an emulator, but the play store update remains the same, it did not change the color or icon (the icon is white with transparency in png).

Does anyone know what might have happened?

Comment: I am also having the same problem with the firebase notifications. Even that I change the icon programatically, it seems to work on some devices and not on some. Following your question for any valid solution.

Comment: @koksalb Exactly, I tested on 2 phones and 1 tablet, one shows the icon of the app and changes the background color, in another it is all white and gray.

Comment: same behavious I am having. I think it is because of firebase library version that is being used (i.e 11.x.x) is not working properly on low API of android or something. But I need more specifications to know the real reason

Comment: @koksalb Does the play store accept the notification icon change? I'm not sure, it's my first app, I'm a beginner.